# Reloading/changing displayed person with ABPersonViewController on iOS7

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, abaddressbook, ios7

I have a class which contains an `ABPersonViewController` child view controller. Until iOS7, I was able to pass the `setDisplayedPerson:` message several times, updating or replacing the displayed information. However, with iOS7, once the `viewDidLoad` fires for the `ABPersonViewController` child view controller, any subsequent calls to `setDisplayedPerson:` are seemingly ignored.

I could replace the child view controller with another, and even animate the transition between them, but this is very inelegant.

There is an open radar for this: rdar://14682982

Anyone seen this?

**Edit:** The issue has been solved with iOS8 beta 1.

Comment: I haven't played with ABPersonViewController in a while, but iOS 7 is still buggy IMO, so this might be worth raising as a bug with Apple.

Comment: Oh, I have a bug report open with Apple on this issue since beta 4. They haven't fixed it yet.

Comment: I still have 4 unresolved.

Comment: Yep, a lot open here too, as well as many duplicated and still open. What a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved in iOS8 beta.

Answer (score 2):

As a temporary workaround, if `ABPersonViewController` is already presented, you can get `ABContactViewController` via `self.navigationController.topViewController.childViewControllers.firstObject` and call `reloadData:` to reload displayed person info.

Comment: Doesn't this just refresh if the currently displayed person has changed, not if you change the displayed person entirely (different `ABRecordRef`)?

Comment: Yes, this will only help  with reloading, not changing. Just found that `ABContactViewController` has undocumented selector `updateWithNewContact:`, will test it now.

Comment: Well, it works with some heavily undocumented workaround, like this: `[controller performSelector: NSSelectorFromString(@"updateWithNewContact:") withObject: [[NSClassFromString(@"CNContact") alloc] initWithRecord: newRecordRef]]`; but contact image is missing.

Comment: I did that too in the betas and it didn't work then. So I guess we can see it as a sign that perhaps in iOS9 timeframe, they will fix it. ;)

Comment: They should just expose ContactViewController and CNContact, instead of the ugly ABRecordRef. Just like they have a wrapper around EventKit. The problem with that, I guess, is CNContact is from another framework entirely, which is "borrowed" here.

Comment: It will be enough if they fix `[ABPersonViewController setDisplayedPerson:]` =)

Comment: Make sure to duplicate my bug report.

Comment: @Entro: Sorry, I don't understand your answer: The problem is to update the information displayed by the ABPersonViewController, but a ABPersonViewController does not have a reloadData: method. What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with the same issue. My current solution is to have the `ABPersonViewController` as a property (I need it in several places) with delayed instantiation, and I set it to nil before using it. In this way I always have a new one to use.

Comment: This is not enough if you want to replace the displayed person after displaying one. What I ended up doing is having a child view controller for each person, if a previous one is displayed, I transition the views with fade.